# template <typename...> meaning / semantics?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I just came across the mysterious `typename...`. What is its semantics?

Obviously it's too general to mean something very specific but still

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename...>
    using Void = void;

    template <typename, typename = void>
    struct EqualityComparableToNullptr
        : std::false_type {};

    template <typename T>
    struct EqualityComparableToNullptr<T, Void<decltype (std::declval<T>() != nullptr)>>
        : std::true_type {};
} // namespace detail
```

Comment: Look at [variadic template/Parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) (C++11).

Comment: You can now have `Void<>`, `Void<int>`, `Void<long, double>` types, any combination, any number of template parameters – as far as your compiler supports...

Answer (score 2):

It is an unnammed [variadic template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). It is used to help with SFINAE in partially specialized classes.  This technique was even added to the standard as [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t).

If you had

```
template <typename>
using Void = void;
```

You would only be able to "convert" one type to `void`, whereas having a variadic template allows you to have N types "convert" to a single `void` type.

Comment: Thanks, can you give some examples of its useful context? Where we would need it

Comment: @barney It's used in places like you have in your Q.  When you want an expression to be a part of SFINAE you need something like this so the expression can be "converted" into a type.  When the expression is valid then `Void<...>` just becomes `void` and the specialization is used.  If the expression is invalid then `decltype` can't be resolved and the specialization is thrown out as a valid candidate since not all parameters can be resolved.